# Custom error page for extension less urls

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, custom-error-pages, wildcard-mapping

I have a DotNetNuke 7 website and I have enabled custom errors like so:

```
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error.aspx">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
```

I also want to add such errors for extension less URLs but when I try to add a wildcard mapping it breaks the site with 404 on the `http://mysite.com` etc

```
<add name="WILDCARDMAPPING" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,bitness64" />
```

How do I setup the handlers..

```
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
        <add name="LogoffHandler*" path="Logoff.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Authentication.LogOffHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="RSSHandler" path="RSS.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Syndication.RssHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="LinkClickHandler" path="LinkClick.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.FileSystem.FileServerHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="CaptchaHandler" path="*.captcha.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.CaptchaHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="UserProfilePageHandler" path="User.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePageHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="RadProgressHandler" verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.Upload.RadUploadProgressHandler, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="UserProfilePicHandler" path="ProfilePic.ashx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.UserProfile.UserProfilePicHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="SitemapHandler" path="Sitemap.aspx" verb="*" type="DotNetNuke.Services.Sitemap.SitemapHandler, DotNetNuke" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="ClientDependencyHandler" verb="*" path="DependencyHandler.axd" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.CompositeDependencyHandler, ClientDependency.Core" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource, Telerik.Web.UI" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler, Telerik.Web.UI, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=121fae78165ba3d4" />
        <add name="HtmTemplateFileHandler" verb="*" path="*.htmtemplate" type="DotNetNuke.Providers.RadEditorProvider.HtmTemplateFileHandler, DotNetNuke.RadEditorProvider" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="WILDCARDMAPPING" path="*" verb="*" type="" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="false" preCondition="integratedMode,bitness64" />
    </handlers>
```

I have tried movie the `WILDCARDMAPPING` handler I added to the top, middle but it doesnt work.

DNN already provides support for extension less urls when there is a page that has been added to the CMS like /Home but shows the normal 404 error message for /somepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/FileNotFound.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to each directory an `index.html` that shows what you would like to display for that case - by default opening `http://SomeUrl/some/path/` always opens/tries to open `http://SomeUrl/some/path/index.html`

Comment: that is not what i want.. i want to show custom error pages when a 404 occures.. so /someurlwithoutextenstion should redirect to /Error.aspx

Answer (score 0):

DNN 7.1 includes the new "Advanced URL Provider" (based on iFinity's URL Master extension), which includes built-in support for 404 pages & extension-less URLs.  There is a page called "404 Error Page" in a new DNN 7.1 site (you have to create it manually in an upgraded site, see the accepted answer at http://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/cid/350985), which will be returned for pages that aren't found (whether there's an extension or not).

Related:

- [DNN 404 Handling](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/DNN-404-Handling) article on DNN's wiki
- [Blog post on 404 handling](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/154518/Page-not-found-404-Error-Handling-in-DNN)